# Model loss stays the same for hours before dropping

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, convergence, train

I'm training a CNN to colorize images. The model I have is not incredibly deep, and should work fine on the card I'm training on (2080 TI). Initially, I suspected the model was flawed in some way because the loss would drop a little bit, and then would stay in the exact place, fluctuating randomly. However, I tried letting it run overnight, and found that my loss would stay the same for a couple hours and then slowly move downward, before reaching another plateau and repeating the whole process over again.

Why is this happening? Is there any way to combat it, so I don't have to wait an absurdly long time for the network to train?

Comment: This is a common finding because radient descent isn't a very good optimizer; this finding is mentioned in passing in http://www.argmin.net/2017/12/05/kitchen-sinks/ If it's feasible for the number of parameters, maybe you can use a better method like Levenberg-Marquardt. If not, maybe look into whether you can achieve "super-convergence"  https://towardsdatascience.com/https-medium-com-super-convergence-very-fast-training-of-neural-networks-using-large-learning-rates-decb689b9eb0

Comment: provide plot of loss curve? what is learning rate schedule?

Comment: @shimao I’ll get a plot when I get home, learning rate is constant